# Bounds in Scipy differential_evolution

Tags: python, optimization, scipy

I am trying to use `differential_evolution` from `Scipy` to do an optimization.

I have 5 parameters, and I want to use `bounds = [(0.0,1.0),(None, None),(0.0, 1.0),(0.0,1.0),(0, None)]`.

But I am getting an error that I have to provide a real number for `(min, max)` for each parameter.

Is there a way to only provides bounds for some parameters when using `differential_evolution`?

I can switch to `basinhopping` to use such bounds, but I would like to use `differential_evolution` because it does not use gradients.

Comment: What happens if you use a np.inf? What happens if you use a huge float e.g. 1e9? Do you really need unbounded or just an enormous bound?

Answer (score 1):

`differential_evolution` is using [`numpy.isfinite`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.isfinite.html#numpy-isfinite) on the bounds after converting it to numpy array to validate the bounds are numberes, it returns `False` for values like `np.inf` and `np.nan`.

You could use the max and min `int` values for numpy instead

```
info = np.iinfo(np.int64)
bounds = [(0.0, 1.0), (info.min, info.max), (0.0, 1.0), (0.0, 1.0), (0, info.max)]
```

Answer (score 0):

`differential_evolution` requires finite bounds for all parameters. Typically this isn't a problem because you can typically guess bounds within a couple of orders of magnitude. I would not recommend using very large numbers (e.g. the largest int) in place of `np.inf` as the algorithm generates population members that are distributed over that range, which is likely to be very inefficient.